# EJB Deployment trouble on Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish, ejb

I need help for a web based java application.
I have an already done project on IntelliJ 14, that contains 3 modules: JSF, EJB and JPA (with eclipse link). The Application container is Glassfish 4.1.
There is no problem during the building, but when i do the deployment on Glassfish...the follow exception is released:

```
"Exception while deploying the app [appname-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT] : 
Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name= ... Local 3.x interface =...,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session. Please see server.log for more details."
```

The server.log is empty (I don't know why)
From IntelliJ I can see the deploy of ejb module is gone well, but the war module made that exception
I think that the war module cannot find the ejb module (where the ejb class are) 
I attach 2 images  with project structure and deploy structure

http://it.tinypic.com/r/r8fp50/8

http://it.tinypic.com/r/30naf4z/8

I spent over 3 days on this issue...and I don't know how I can do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in glassfish 4.1 when it has to deploy ejb, try using glassfish 4, in that one i did not encounter that problem, I think the problem is the jersey lib in glassfish 4.1